# RequestedMapping with multiple parameters

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a jsp page with a dropdownmenu and 2 buttons submit and cancel. 
Based on the value of the dropdown and the button that is clicked a different jsppage is supposed to be opend.

In my controller I used a request mapping with the value of the dropdown and butto as a param so for cancel would this be @RequestMapping(param="cancel")

So when the url equals ?cancel=true the methods get's executed, but when I click my cancel button the url is ?cancel=, which results in a 404. How do I get it to return true?

Also if I have a second param do I have to include it in my statement or can I only use age? I tried both and neighter worked.

Finally if I have to include all the parameters can I use a wildcard for the value?

I included my code, but keep in mind I was trying out my bottens, so my controller class isn't finished yet.

The ageSelector.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select your age</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<button type="submit" name="submit"    
    formaction="submit">submit</button> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <button type="cancel" name="cancel" formaction="cancel">cancel</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just remembered i removed my dropdown for testing...

My controllerclass:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("ages")
public class AgeController {
    @RequestMapping(params="submit")
    public String handleSubmit(){
        return "childern";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params="cancel")
    public String handleCancel(){
        return "cancel";
    }

    @RequestMapping()
    public String handleDefault(){
        return "ageSelection";
    }
}
```

I think that's about al the info you need.
Sorry for my crappy English I'm not native.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different submit forms on the same page:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" formaction="submit">submit</button> 
</form>
<form>
    <button type="submit" name="cancel" formaction="cancel">cancel</button>
</form>
```

BTW, better to have those two actions mapped to different methods inside you controller by path rather than the parameter (just more natural way):

```
<form name="submitionForm" action="submit">
    <button type="submit">submit</button> 
</form>
<form name="cancellationForm" action="cancel">
    <button type="submit">cancel</button>
</form>
```

Then in your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("ages")
public class AgeController {

    @RequestMapping("/submit")
    public String handleSubmit(){
        return "childern";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/cancel")
    public String handleCancel(){
        return "cancel";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public String handleDefault(){
        return "ageSelection";
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but then my submit button should work and that one dosn't work either

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but didn't work for me

Comment: What does it say in logs? What's the error message?

Comment: 405 RequestMethod.GET not supported